# Safari displays blank pages for some sites

Tags: macos, safari, display, firefox, websites

Some pages, sometimes on Apple's on support site simply display as blank pages. The same page displays perfectly on Firefox or Chrome. What is this strange behaviour? For example, this link: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH15327 shows a completely blank page.

[image]

The same site displays without problem in Firefox. (Can't post image due to low reputation.)

I have no extensions installed in Safari. JS is enabled, all settings are default. This is a fresh and clean install of Yosemite.

What's going on. Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit 1: As an aside, and I don't have specific data for this, but Safari does seem to load some other pages so slowly, it's annoying to the extreme.

Comment: We think it's that the kb link is to one apple site, but your cookies are to another - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162196/apple-knowledgebase-pages-often-blank for a workaround without clearing cookies all the time.

Comment: I ought to flag this as a dupe, so both questions get linked together for future searchers

Answer (score 1):

Okay, please don't hate me, but I just cleared the cache and cookies and voila!, the pages are displaying again. But you have to agree that this is neither expected nor acceptable behaviour for a mainstream browser, is it?

Comment: It's incredible how buggy Safari is compared with other browsers.