# Where else can I download the legacy Java SE 6 runtime?

Tags: macos, java

I just upgraded to OSX Yosemite.

I am trying to open my Adobe Flash CS6 app, but it says

> To open "Flash" you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime.

A simple google search yields this page: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6604985

There are several links there - however, they all lead to the same site: a downloads page from Apple that offer the required Java SE runtime. The page is the following:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

But it cannot be viewed, since it has a redirect loop.

Where else can I download this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to https://www.apple.com/support/ then search for DL1572

See [Apple Knowledgebase pages often blank](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162196/apple-knowledgebase-pages-often-blank)

<sup>EDIT - or in this case, not… as it doesn't seem to fix it</sup>

**Update:**
Original KB link appears to be working again.
Would appear to have been an Apple issue, now resolved.
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Comment: If I perform such search, it sends me to this page: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US - which has a redirect loop.

Comment: Yeah, it usually works, but I'm getting nowhere fast on that one right now

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that the page is set to redirect to itself.

Using the [Live HTTP Headers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/iaiioopjkcekapmldfgbebdclcnpgnlo?hl=en) plugin for Chrome shows the following code being returned by the server.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: no-siteapp
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 18 Apr 2015 20:08:55 GMT
Location: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_GB
Server: AkamaiGHost
```

Essentially telling it to redirect to itself. Not sure though whether this is a problem on Apple's server or Akamai's.

A bunch of their download pages seem to be broken right now. Even the [main download page](https://support.apple.com/downloads/) has this redirect issue at the moment.